# Marionette and ASP.NET MVC4 working sample

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, marionette

Has anybody here seen working sample/source code of Marionette and asp.net mvc? I've found one asp.net mvc sample project under project sections of Marionettejs but that is outdated and doesn't work either. So can somebody tell me precisely where I can get one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this?
https://github.com/priley86/marionette-mvc4-bootstrap-template

I know it's an old question, but better late then never :)

Comment: yes I've had this one already... this is still far off from pro app... by that I mean primitive func. like session and user/role management etc